# Java - Selenium WebElement isDisplayed() method not available

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium (2.44.0) for my Java Unit tests, and I'm trying to use [WebElement](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed())'s `isDisplayed()` method, but it doesn't appear to be available.  I can only see the `isEnabled()` and `isSelected()` methods.

(*Error message in Eclipse: "The method isDisplayed() is undefined for the type WebElement"*)

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.499</version>
    <!-- which version of Hudson is this plugin built against? -->
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<artifactId>extended-choice-parameter</artifactId>
<packaging>hpi</packaging>
<version>0.35-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Extended Choice Parameter Plug-In</name>
<url>http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin</url>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>vimil</id>
        <name>Vimil Saju</name>
    </developer>
</developers>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>InjectedTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>            
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-common</artifactId>
          <version>2.0b1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 

<!-- get every artifact through maven.glassfish.org, which proxies all the artifacts that we need -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
        <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
        <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
    <id>maven.jenkins-ci.org</id>
    <url>http://maven.jenkins-ci.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>
</distributionManagement>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/jenkinsci/extended-choice-parameter-plugin.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/jenkinsci/extended-choice-parameter-plugin.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/extended-choice-parameter-plugin</url>
</scm>
```

Java code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

.......

    WebElement element;
    int size = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='type']")).size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='type']")).get(i);
        if (element.isDisplayed()) {
            select = new Select(element);
            select.selectByVisibleText("Multi-Level Multi Select");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

**EDIT** - added full pom.xml and eclipse error message to clarify issue

**EDIT (2)** - changed Java code to actual (used) Java code regarding *@Vivek Singh* 's first comment about exception handling

Comment: Don't really know what happened here. But out of curiosity won't findElement throw you an exception if the element is not found? So in that case won't isDisplayed be an unreachable line? Any views on this are welcome.

Comment: What is the version of selenium-api.jar do you have?

Comment: What does "doesn't appear to be available" mean? Is there an error? Anything?

Comment: @Vivek Singh, yes it may not reach that line that case, but my issue is that the method `isDisplayed` itself is not available at all, so in my Eclipse IDE, it would be underlined in red.

Comment: @minion  selenium-api.jar version 2.35.0

Comment: Can you please force update your project using maven? or clean and build it again?

Comment: @SiKing yes, the `isDisplayed()` method would be underlined in red in my Eclipse IDE.  As I mentioned, only the `isSelected()` and `isEnabled` methods are available.
@Vivek Singh   yes, my project is up-to-date

Comment: It is quite strange to get selenium-api 2.35.0 by defining selenium-java 2.44.0. As far as I can see, versions should be aligned. That said, both api 2.35.0 and 2.44.0 do contain the _isDisplayed()_ method.

Comment: @Tome  Ok, I updated the selenium-api version to 2.44.0 and ran another maven force update, but I still don't see the `isDisplayed()` method.  Should I post more from my pom.xml?  Maybe something else could also be conflicting

Comment: Can you post your pom completely? Somehow your WebElement reference is getting messed up.

Comment: The dependency over selenium-common stinks (a lot). Just remove every selenium dependency except selenium-java.

Comment: @Tome  It works.

I was using selenium-common to get rid of the "The type org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasInputDevices cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" error I was encountering before in another test class.  Also, the selenium-api dependency prevents the `isDisplayed()` method from being usable as well.

selenium-chrome-driver doesn't conflict, so now I have selenium-java and selenium-chrome-driver without any issue.  

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: **edit to previous comment:**    selenium-api does *not* prevent `isDisplayed()` method from working.  The workspace must have not finished updating when I checked..

Comment: Just had a look at your pom. Why are you having all those selenium related dependencies when you can have them all in one under selenium-server version 2.44.0 dependency?

Comment: @Vivek Singh  I mentioned previously I added selenium-common to resolve the 'HasInputDevices' error, and for some reason I needed selenium-chrome-driver for my WebDriver to work, but now it's fine without it. I tried your suggestion to use *only* selenium-server version 2.44.0 in pom and I get this error when I try to run my test class "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/net/MediaType".  I get the same error if I have only selenium-java as well.  Both selenium-server and selenium-java seem to need selenium-api, otherwise I get that error.

Comment: @lkisac That error occurs cause you are not having guava dependency. That error is no where linked to selenium. I suggest you to add server and guava dependency and remove rest _selenium_ dependencies and force update or clean the project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70664/discussion-between-lkisac-and-vivek-singh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium commons brings in WebElement.java in exactly the same package structure which does not have isDisplayed() method. So your reference was messed up. Don't include selenium-commons in your pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly like @tome said. selenium-common.jar is version 2.0b1. `isDisplayed()` was added in Selenium 2.0 (final). Until then it was located in other classes. So `selenium-common` masks `selenium-api` and this is the reason why you can't compile.

Comment: In my experience using Selenium 2.44.0 and commons-lang 3.x,  I don't have any problems with it. It works fine.